# C# IDE for Android

Tags: android, software-development, ide, c#

One of the reasons I purchased an Android phone was that I saw an IDE that looked exactly like Visual C# on someone's Android phone. Ever since I purchased mine, I have searched on Google, Google Play, but I have not been able to find a C# IDE like that.

I need a C# IDE like Visual C# on PC for Android.

Comment: Remote Desktop Protocol,
it lets your connect to a (suitably set up) windows computer, as it you were sitting in front of it,


There are some good free android clients.

Comment: Perhaps it was this that you saw? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gregshackles.csharptogo I won't put it in an answer as I have never used it and know nothing about it.

Comment: There is a reddit [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/9nvkcr/any_good_android_c_ide_app) on this, but unfortunately, all the suggestions are websites