# IDE to develop C# apps for Android

Tags: android, c#, ide

I want to develop an Android app, and there is a particular C# library I must use, so I am thinking of writing the whole app in C# (an Java/C# hybrid solution is also OK if that exists).

What IDE can I use?

- Runs on Linux, or Mac, or Windows (the more the better)
- Free, ideally open source
- Generated app must be releasable under the license I want (for instance open source). This means that any library embedded by the IDE should be either GNU-GPLv3 or more liberal (public domain would be ideal)
- Code autocompletion
- Live debugging using real device (emulator also OK)
- I don't need the IDE itself to run on Android, which is [another question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/709/c-ide-for-android)

Answer (score 2):

[**Xamarin**](http://xamarin.com/)

If you love C# and want to create an Android application using that language then you have to thank Xamarin as they created this great Cross Platform development tool which enables developers to develop iOS and Android apps in C# language.

Xamarin is offered in different licenses from free to enterprise levels.

[image]

For more info and tutorial to develop `Android app using C#` visit : [Developing Android Apps using C# @codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/663461/Developing-Android-Apps-using-Csharp)

Comment: Xamarin or some of their licensing plans don't match with the "Generated app must be releasable under the license I want (for instance open source). This means that any library embedded by the IDE should be either GNU-GPLv3 or more liberal (public domain would be ideal)" requirement. Xamarin's embedded libraries are commercial, as such Xamarin is not the best platform for open source projects.

Comment: Xamarin SDK is open source since 2016.